# Difference between Pragmatics and Sociolinguistics

Tags: pragmatics, sociolinguistics

I have been doing some intense research on *sociolinguistics* and *pragmatics* and am becoming more and more confused as to what the distinction between them is.

If someone could **describe** both concepts and then **highlight** their similarities and differences, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Off-topic for this stack, I'd think. Might be better to post (or search) on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Obviously, *sociolinguistics* is broad; *progmatics* is specific.

Comment: All the same, as @tmgr said, over to linguistics.

Comment: The Q belongs on [linguistics.se]

Answer (score 2):

The study of language in relation to social factors, including differences of regional, class, and occupational dialect, gender differences, and bilingualism This is what we call as Sociolinguistics, where as Pragmatics is the branch of linguistics dealing with language in use and the contexts in which it is used, including such matters as deixis, the taking of turns in conversation, text organization, presupposition, and implicature.
Thus both the fields even though looks similar but there is a difference. Hope I have cleared your dilemma.